# Get the output of a form as though the submit button was pressed

Tags: javascript, forms, get, form-submit

I have recently been employed as a web developer on a website, and to be honest, the existing code is a bit of a mess.
The code is hardly commented, all of the variable names are vague, and what's more, the site doesn't seem to do what it is intended too.

One of the pages (which is what this question is wondering) has update buttons for sections of a form (it is a shopping cart, so the sections of the form are printed multiple times, each one has an update button). And a main submit button. The issue is that the submit button doesn't take into account any changes on the current page load (only the update buttons do this)!

The code is a bit of a mess, and really needs re-coding, but time isn't available for this. I was therefore wondering, if there is a was to get the variables out of the form without the update buttons being pressed - with a small javascript/JQuery script, perhaps.

If tl;dr, I am looking for a script that will return the output of the form (it is a GET form) every time it is updated, as though a submit button has been pressed!

Thanks

Comment: Put another way, the form is submitted to a server-side script and you would like to call that server-side script, passing it certain values and obtain the script's response. Did I get that right?

Comment: Essentially, yes.
I have the form, and the script, but the form is a mess of foreach loops, and badly named variables with no comments, so I was wondering if there was a way to get all of the values out of the form - formatted in the same way that a GET request would receive!

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about the PHP which is parsed to produce your form. This makes me think we have our wires crossed. A small code sample demonstrating what you mean would be helpful.

Comment: Hm, ok, I'll try to explain it better.
I want some javascript (or something similar!) that can get the contents of a form and run a script every time the form changes.
For example, I may have a form with field names 'Name' and 'DoB'.
I'd want the script to return something along the lines of Name="Dan"&DoB="ddmmyyyy"!
Does that make more sense?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/j5vqw4wz/